# architecture for single producer multiple consumers

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, architecture

I am in the process of designing a GUI to display market data. Currently, I have multiple windows that consume the same data but display different aspects of it. I am trying to figure out the best way to architect this system.

I have a single producer of market data and multiple consumers which register a callback with the producer. When the producer is ready with data, it iterates through a list of consumers and distributes data to each consumer via the callback. I'm not sure if this is the best method to distribute data. Each consumer has to wait for the previous consumer to finish processing the callback before it can get its data.

Is there a way by which all consumers can get data at the same time or with minimal delays ? I am using C# 4.0 and would like to know if there are any language features which enable this.

Comment: Too broad for a single answer. voted to close.

Comment: Try to reduce the problem and illustrate with some code.

Comment: You are thinking about this the wrong way.  The requirement that consumers have to wait for each other collapses the problem.  You do *not* have N consumers that perform 1 operation each, you have 1 consumer that performs N operations.  That's trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for a fairly simple solution by using a separate [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) per consumer.

The producer thread just needs a `List<>` of [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) queues that it manages itself. When the producer thread produces an item, it just needs to add it to *each* queue in the list using `BlockingCollection.Add()`. Note: That is the *same item* being queued multiple times - once to each consumer queue.

The item type should be an immutable reference type - then it is safe to share among the consumers AND the overhead is just a reference in each consumer queue.

This isn't the most efficient route since it requires a queue per consumer, but I don't think it's too bad unless the queues are big. It's very easy to understand and implement though.

A `BlockingCollection` makes it very easy to tell the consumer threads when there is no more data so that they can exit cleanly.

The producer thread calls [`BlockingCollection.CompleteAdding()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287086.aspx) to signal to the consuming thread that they should exit when there is no more data.

Meanwhile, all the consuming threads need to do is this (assuming `queue` is their BlockingCollection queue):

```
foreach (var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    ... process item
}
```

That's it. The consumers will automatically block in the `foreach` loop when there is no more data, and they will automatically exit the `foreach` when there is no more data *and* the producer has called `CompleteAdding()`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [Reactive Extensions Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)? It should be idea for what you describe and it gives great flexibility. Here is how to manage [multiple subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242977%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: If the application is running all InProcess RX is indeed a good option

Comment: You should include some code in your answer - right now it's pretty much link-only.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenarios you should use a Queue such as RabbitMQ or MSMQ. They are optimal for this types of publisher/subscriber operations.

If that's not an option you can trigger the callbacks using threads or set them as WCF fire and forget calls (OneWay).

Answer (score 0):

If it's important that each of the registered callbacks are called from their own thread (most likely a thread pool thread) that's easy enough to do:

```
public class Foo
{
    private HashSet<Action> callbacks = new HashSet<Action>();
    public event Action MyEvent
    {
        add
        {
            callbacks.Add(value);
        }
        remove
        {
            callbacks.Remove(value);
        }
    }

    private void FireMyEvent()
    {
        foreach (var action in callbacks)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => { action(); });
        }
    }
}
```